# Any examples of production applications that use signature trees?

Tags: database, data-structures, indexing, theory

I've been reading a lot lately about signature trees, or S-Trees. For example, [this paper](http://en.scientificcommons.org/43485787). The literature speaks very highly of them, and evidence is provided for considerable performance gains over, for example, inverted files or B-Trees, for some applications.

Now, why is it that I don't see S-Trees used very much? Do you know of any prominent instances of such a data structure in a popular application? Are there DBMS implementations that offer signature-tree indexes?

Answer (score 3):

> Now, why is it that I don't see `S-Trees` used very much?

Including a new indexing or join method into a database is a very complex task.

`MySQL`, for instance, doesn't yet impement `MERGE JOIN` and `HASH JOIN` that were invented by, like, ancient Romans or Archimedes or around that time.

And the paper you referenced is dated `2006` and this method isn't even mentioned in `Wikipedia`.

This means that it's either yet unknown to developers or isn't worth using it in an `RDBMS` (or both).

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of something similar described as being a "C-tree" - it was part of an object database and I imagined that its indexing methods were similar to what the paper in the link described. A company called InterSystems makes a database system called Caché that they describe as "post-relational" and is very hierarchical ... I don't know enough about the details of these different systems to be sure that they're all different names for the same functionality, but, they have some overlapping fundamental concepts.